# JS convert string to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

sorry for question, i'm noob in JS. I have string:

```
[{&#34;priceEm&#34;: 28000, &#34;priceId&#34;: &#34;25094967&#34;}]
```

How i can convert in to array

```
['priceEm': 28000, 'priceId':'25094967']
```

and iterate thru array, not thru string

Answer (score 2):

Generate a temporary DOM element with the string as HTML content(by setting [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) property) and finally get the [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) which would be the decoded data.

```js
var str = '[{&#34;priceEm&#34;: 28000, &#34;priceId&#34;: &#34;25094967&#34;}]';

// create a temporary div element
var temp = document.createElement('div');
// set the html content
temp.innerHTML = str;
// get the text content
console.log(temp.textContent);
```

---

Or with `textarea` do the same and get the [`value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) finally.

```js
var str = '[{&#34;priceEm&#34;: 28000, &#34;priceId&#34;: &#34;25094967&#34;}]';

// generate a temporary textarea
var temp = document.createElement('textarea');
// set the html content
temp.innerHTML = str;
// get the value of the element
console.log(temp.value);
```

---

**UPDATE :** The result is a valid JSON data, you can iterate after passing the JSON string using [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) method.

```js
var str = '[{&#34;priceEm&#34;: 28000, &#34;priceId&#34;: &#34;25094967&#34;}]';

var temp = document.createElement('textarea');
temp.innerHTML = str;

// parse the JSON string 
var arr = JSON.parse(temp.value);

console.log(arr[0]);

// iterate over the array
arr.forEach(function(obj) {
  console.log(obj);
  // iterate over the object properties
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(k) {
    console.log(k, obj[k]);
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Pranav's answer is close. You'll need to parse it as an object finally to access its properties:

```
var str = '[{&#34;priceEm&#34;: 28000, &#34;priceId&#34;: &#34;25094967&#34;}]';

var temp = document.createElement('div');
temp.innerHTML = str;

var finalObj = JSON.parse(temp.textContent)[0];
```